# Если на открытке написать "С праздниками - Днем весны и труда и днем победы" тире будет считаться ошибкой?

Tags: дефис-тире

Если на открытке написать "С праздниками - Днем весны и труда и днем победы" тире будет считаться ошибкой?

Answer (score 1):

Официальное название – Праздник Весны и Труда. Так что верно так: **С Праздником Весны и Труда и Днём Победы**.